# Is there a continuity error in the Westworld series with the Angel investor?

Tags: westworld-2016

Related to [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152412/why-does-this-character-commit-suicide-in-westworld) StackExchange question about a character suicide is there a continuity error in the Westworld series? I.e. we see this character commit suicide to try and prevent the park from opening. According to Ford and the Man in Black, after this character commits suicide and all the other hosts:

> are killed by Dolores and Teddy

The Westworld Wiki similarly supports this timeline for the character profile:

[Character Profile](http://westworld.wikia.com/wiki/Arnold_Weber)

> Arnold was killed approximately 34 years before Dr. Ford interviewed Dolores in "Contrapasso"[1](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/152412/why-does-this-character-commit-suicide-in-westworld) ***("Right before the park opened.").*** [2](http://westworld.wikia.com/wiki/Arnold_Weber)

In another quote from Ford:

"For three years we lived here in the park, refining the hosts before a single guest set foot inside," Ford explained. "Myself, a team of engineers, and my partner."

the only reason the park is still able to open is because of an 'Angel' investor that provided funding to get everything fixed.

Supposedly this is:

> Ed Harris as the Man in Black.

But, it is also revealed that:

> The Man is Black is actually an older William who used his new wife's families fortune to buy a major investment in the park and become a board member.

However, this character did not

> invest in the park until after he visited and his future brother-in-law Logan had visited multiple times before. In fact, Logan told William in Episode 5 while they were at the park about how Arnold’s suicide put the park in financial “free fall” and that the company where both he and William work was thinking of buying more shares and therefore rescuing the park.

Therefore how could he have been the 'Angel' investor that helped the park to open in the first place?

Comment: http://media.vanityfair.com/photos/5819a3c4827d57cf27da6e07/master/w_690,c_limit/ww-mib-angel-investor.gif

Comment: Thanks Valorum.  This is exactly why I think there is a continuity issue. The character suicide was presented as a way to keep the park from opening as per what the Wiki site lists for the character profile.  But, at the same time it had to have opened for the angel investor to be as described. That angel only agreed after the park was opened.  These appear to conflict.

Comment: But where is it stated that William's investment came before the park opened? I didn't get that impression at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman. Correct.  it would seem that William's investment had to come after the park opened. I.e. he was visiting with his future brother-in-law when he decided to do so.  Valorum's link confirms that supposedly William also made the investment when the character in question committed suicide and saved the park from financial ruin and from going under.  But if you read  the character profile link I attached and watch the series it is clearly stated that the character committed suicide BEFORE the park opened to keep it from opening. That is why I am asking about a continuity error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In S2E2 it is revealed that

> the angel investor is Logan Delos

After he is visited

> in the real world by Aketecha and Angela posing as the park's founders

There is no continuity error in this case. This occurs well before William's first visit.

Comment: Yep.  Agreed. I saw this as it came out and had the same thought. It also did a good job explaining how William came to be effectively the 'second' angel investor via his new family connection.In Valorum's link:  http://media.vanityfair.com/photos/5819a3c4827d57cf27da6e07/master/w_690,c_limit/ww-mib-angel-investor.gif    William is referring to saving the park a second time.  But, the reference is still a bit odd as the context implies William saved it directly after the suicide.

Answer (score 2):

> It is never explicitly mentioned that William was the investor who allowed the park to open

Your comment

> However, this character did not invest in the park until after he visited

may be true, but the below dialog line between William and Logan suggests there was already active investment in the park before William met Dolores

> I am going to make sure our company **substantially increases** our holdings in the park

and when Ford says

> I found or rather, you found, an investor who believed in this place.

Perhaps Dolores was seducing other unseen investors prior to William? It's implied the "angel" was William but never explicitly stated.

Comment: During the early park of their park adventure, Logan also mentions to William how the Park is haemorrhaging money.

Comment: True Williams future investment allows the park to thrive and has no bearing on it staying open. By the time William first comes to the park the suicide in question has already happened.

Comment: @Mike this fact is confirmed in Episode 9, when Charlotte talks to William/Man-in-Black after he escapes the "game" that Wyatt-Girl set up for him. She says "after all, it was you who kept Ford in business all those years ago"

Comment: @Mike. Great speculation that Dolores was possibly seducing other unseen investors. As we see in Season 2 that was exactly what she was doing.  +1 for the suggestion as we found out it was spot on.

Answer (score 2):

### Logan and William's visit in in a period after Ford's partner's death, but before the park has been "saved" by the angel investor.

In other words, I think this may just be timeline confusion. Very understandable given the nature of this show.

**Before The Park Opens:**

> Arnold makes Dolores and Teddy kill all of the hosts, and then makes Dolores kill him.

**Just After The Park Opens:**

Logan visits the park and falls in love with it. He learns that the company is struggling and considers having his company invest and save it. He knows that Ford's partner died, and that his death somehow triggered the park's problems, but he isn't able to find out anything else about him.

**Just Before The Park is "Saved":**

Logan brings William on a bonding/initiation/business-ish visit, where

> William is "born" as the Man In Black, decides to take over Logan's company, and also decides to save the park.